# Show/Hide Div Based on URL using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I want to show a DIV ONLY when on /../mahjong.php. So even if I go to /../mahjong.php?layout it should hide the div (since it's not the same url)

I have tried the following:

```
// We're NOT on the home page
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/games/mahjong/mahjong.php") >= 0) {
  $style = "display: none";
}
else {
  $style = "display: inline";
}
```

And my div ofcourse:

```
<div class="menu" id="menu" style="<?php echo $style; ?>">
```

But if I go to /games/mahjong/mahjong.php?layout it doesn't change the style. I've echoed:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and it changes to /games/mahjong/mahjong.php?layout, so why isn't the style set to inline?

```
 if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/games/mahjong/mahjong.php") === false) {
```

Didn't work either. (this wil show the div and never hide it) What am I missing?

Many thanks,

Maurice

Comment: You might want to stick this conditional statement directly into your template file and only show the div when the case is `true`, because there's no reason to print HTML that isn't displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition to:

```
strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/games/mahjong/mahjong.php') === strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) - strlen('/games/mahjong/mahjong.php')
```

This will make sure the request uri ends with that string.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `$_GET` array has been populated or not:

```
<?php if (empty($_GET)): ?>
<div>
...
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Should be sufficient if you're not manually adding to the `$_GET` array, which would be very silly.

Comment: Does `$_GET` contain the same info that is populated in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`?

Comment: No, but it contains whatever's in the query string if present.

Comment: What if the URL is `/foo/bar.php/more/info?var1=val1&var2=val2`

Answer (score 0):

strpos(); only search for that string, and in both cases, string is found
strpos(); isn'T exact search !

```
// We're NOT on the home page
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/games/mahjong/mahjong.php?layout") >= 0) {
  $style = "display: inline";
}
else {
  $style = "display: none";
}
```

or you can use

```
// We're NOT on the home page
if (isset($_GET['layout'])) {
  $style = "display: inline";
}
else {
  $style = "display: none";
}
```

this might help

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `PATH_INFO` AND `QUERY_STRING` are empty...if not, then it's not the page you want.